# Dependance and independace of relations

Tags: definition

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group, and let $\prod_{i=1}^ng_i^{e_i}=1$, $\prod_{i=1}^mh_i^{f_i}=1$ be two multiplicative relations in $G$. What does it mean that these two relation are independent?

Comment: Relations are dependent if one can be deduced from the others.  If $g_1^2=e=g_2^3$ then $g_1^2g_2^3=e$ would be a dependent relation.  Of course, it's a more subtle dependence than, say, that of linear dependence in a vector space.  Knowing that relation $A$ implies relation $B$ does not tell you that $B$ implies $A$.  In a free group, it can be profoundly difficult (even undecidable) to determine whether a collection of relations is dependent.

Comment: Now I understand... Thank you!